# Coupling in OO design

Tags: coupling, oop

I have two objects. A Meeting object and an Action object (action raised in a meeting). An Action can also exist independent of a Meeting. I have two ways of linking the Action raised to the Meeting:

1. have a method on Meeting where I
   pass in the Action object such as
   "addToMeeting(Action action)".
   WIthin the internals of Meeting
   I then link the action to the
   meeting. For this approach though the
   Meeting object needs to know about
   and use the methods on the Action
   object so becomes coupled.
2. have a method on Meeting where I just pass
   the action number to be linked such
   as "addToMeeting(int actionID)".
   Great now Meeting object does not
   need to know anything about Action
   but......now the code adding the
   action to the meeting needs to know
   how to get the action ID so has
   turned from this
   "meeting.addToMeeting(action)" to
   this
   "meeting.addToMeeting(action.getID())".

For good OO design, which approach should be used? Or is there a third way....

Comment: I think that you may find a book ([view it online](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=9CL446IzhuAC&pg=PA38&lpg=PA38&dq=events+chapter+one+coupling&source=bl&ots=qmJTOuCz90&sig=EZKvZBjF8QmGohatC97HsmAqG0c&hl=en&ei=wj6tTqe5LcTX8gON_YyiCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=events%20chapter%20one%20coupling&f=false)) "Event-based programming: taking events to the limit
 " Don't take the title at face value - Chapter One gives an insightful description and method by which to reduce/shift coupling to lesser forms of coupled behavior.

Answer (score 5):

**If the only think you ever plan on linking to `Meeting` instances are actions, then it would seem most appropriate to make `Meeting` aware of `Action`, rather than the other way around.**

Having the `Actions` class manipulate the internals of `Meeting` breaks encapsulation and generally makes it harder to maintain such code. So, I would expose a method `addAction(Action a)` on `Meeting` in this case.

**However, if there are other things that can be linked to a meeting, you may want to consider abstracting the concept of "meeting items".**

Rather than have `Meeting` know about `Action`, or vice verse, you could define an interface such as `IMeetingItem` which exposes the necessary information that `Meeting` would need to link to such items. `Action` would then implement `IMeetingItem`, making it possible to do something like:

```
meeting.addItem( action );  // action treated as an IMeetingItem in this context
```

---

Note that in both approaches, it is the `Meeting` class that mediates the functionality of adding an item to itself, rather than having the item being added manipulate the internal representation of a meeting.

Comment: Thanks. Really like second part as this means I can add this interface to any object I want to add to a meeting (e.g. an issue) and meeting only needs to know about the interface.

Comment: Second this. Intuitively, meetings exist to decide what to do, so it makes sense that `Meeting` knows about `Action`. On the other hand, in a reasonably productive company, not all kinds of actions will be about managing meetings, so that relation is not needed in the most general interface of actions.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you create an interface "Identifiable" with the method getID() on it which is implemented by Action

Then you can do the following:

```
addToMeeting(Identifiable action);
```

and inside the method do

```
this.actionId = action.getID();
```

Comment: Thanks. This will work well. Rather than identifiable, I will use "MeetingItem" interface which will allow me to attached any item to a meeting that implements the interface as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

As long as meetings are associated with actions in any way, you'll have some coupling. However, you might consider a third approach, to build an "action factory" that generates action objects. ID would be a property on the Action object, once it's created (and maybe saved). All that meeting would do is tell the factory to generate an action, and be able to access the action's ID property.

Comment: While that may be the best approach in some situations, (assuming the example we're looking at isn't a dumbed down version of the OPs problem domain) I think it adds unnecessary complications to a simple situation.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Most instructive.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with option #1 -- coupling is not a bad thing, in your case, since there is a clear relation between objects. I would go with option #1. This gives you the option for a meeting to have a property of `MeetingActions[]` or something similar.